# Which Ubuntu to go with?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, 13.04, dual-boot

I'm really stuck into which Ubuntu I should choose. I'm stuck between 12.04, 12.10, 13.04, 13.10. I have used 12.10 before but wondering if that was the right choice. I'll be dual booting with Windows but Ubuntu will be on a separate drive.

System specs:
i5 3570k 
560ti 1gb 
Corsair 8gb 1600mhz
64 bit architecture
Asus P8Z77 V-LK

Any help in deciding would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There is not a lot of difference between the 3. Either will work (Ubuntu does not often change in such a way that you must get a new computer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend sticking with an LTS, in this case, 12.04 LTS.  You get 5 years of support rather than a mere 9 months.  So unless you always want to be on the cutting edge, 12.04 LTS will treat you right.

Comment: Any cons to using 12.04?

Comment: Yeah it is boring using lts >:D

Comment: Why is it boring? lol

Answer (score 1):

A non-LTS release gets updated for the following nine months only. An LTS is updated for five years.

If you go for a non-LTS release you would usually update to a new release every six months - for example from 10.04LTS to 10.10 to 11.04 and so on until you get to the next LTS.

The choice is stick with an LTS, update to every new release or pick and choose which you are going to update and which you will skip.

If you aren't likely to be interested in the technical details of each release and want a stable environment, stick with 12.04 LTS until next April when 14.04 LTS is out and that will be supported for five years too.

Otherwise if you want to try out all the new stuff as it is developed, update for every release and install 13.10 the latest development release.

Comment: Now I understand the gist of the matter, more facts, less opinion, thanks!